# spl_autoload_register não funciona

Tags: php, mvc, php-autoload, spl-autoloader-register

Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema em mvc. Desenvolvendo localmente, tudo funcionou corretamente... Mas quando coloquei online para poder testar, ele simplesmente não carregava, dava erro 500. Então comecei a tentar encontrar o erro. Coloquei echo 'test' dentro de spl_autoload_register para ver se ele estava entrando na função, mas não está. Ele não encontra minha class core porque nem entra na função spl_autoload_register :(

Eu não consigo imaginar o que poderia ser, se é alguma configuração do servidor ou algo assim. Localmente estou rodando php 7.4 e online 7.2

Erro foi:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Core' not found in /home/server/public_html/index.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /home/server/public_html/index.php on line 31

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // Connection to database
    require('config.php');

    // Checking if the files exist in 'controller', 'core' and 'models'
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {

        if(file_exists('sources/controllers/'.$class.'.php')) {

            // Controllers
            require 'sources/controllers/'.$class.'.php';

        } else if(file_exists('sources/models/'.$class.'.php')) {

            // Models
            require 'sources/models/'.$class.'.php';

        } else if(file_exists('core/'.$class.'.php')) {

            // Core
            require 'core/'.$class.'.php';

        }

    });

    // Class core
    $core = new Core();

    $core->start();

?>
```

Comment: Era o nome do arquivo core que estava com C minusculo

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! Mas tente trabalhar com a mesma versão de PHP nos 2 ambientes!